# bash While? loop choice menu

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter your Host Name"
read hname
echo "You have entered $hname, is this correct?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) sh runscript.sh; break;;
         No ) ;
    esac
done
```

How can I make this work so that if answer is incorrect go back to ask it again?
I know I need a `while` loop to achieve this but don't know how to write it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
while [ "$yn" != "Yes" ]; do
 echo "Please enter your Host Name"
 read hname
 echo "You have entered $hname, is this correct? (Yes or No)"
  read yn
done
sh runscript.sh
```

Comment: you get the points for this, thanks for the fast reply answered within 15 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one you helped me out on writing:

```
#!/bin/bash

        while ["$yn" != "Yes" ]; do

    echo "Choose your type of installation"

    echo "1) Home Media Server"

    echo "2) Home Communication Server"

    echo "3) Enterprise Communication Server"

    echo "4) Hosting Server"

    echo "5) Individual Packages"

    echo "6) exit"

    read case;



    #simple case bash structure

    # note in this case $case is variable and does not have to

    # be named case this is just an example



    case $case in

        1) echo "You have entered Home Media Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Home Media Server";;



        2) echo "You have entered Home Communication Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Home Communication Server";;



        3) echo "You have entered Enterprise Communication Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Enterprise Communication Server";;



        4) echo "You have entered Hosting Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Hosting Server";;



        5) echo "You have entered $hname, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Individual Packages";;



        6) exit

    esac
```

Thanks once again.